# Calculating confidence intervals

Tags: self-study, hypothesis-testing

Body mass index was compared for two groups, people with elevated triglycerides (above 1.7 mmol/L) and people with normal triglyceride levels. The 10 people in the group with elevated triglyceride had body mass index mean = 26.1 and standard deviation = 3.72 and the 15 people in the normal group had body mass index mean = 24.3 and S = 3.45.

What are the confidence intervals for these means and without doing any further calculations, decide whether a test of the null hypothesis of no difference against a two-sided alternative at 5% would lead to rejection or not

Comment: Please change the title to something more informative and if this is homework, add the `homework` tag.

Answer (score 1):

What part are you stuck on? Try to solve it one step at a time.

The data is:

$\overline x_1 = 26.1, s_1 = 3.72, n_1 = 10\\ 
\overline x_2 = 24.3, s_2 = 3.45, n_2 = 15$

Find the confidence interval for $\mu_1$. Then, separately, find the confidence interval for $\mu_2$.

The next part is basically saying: What would be the result of a test of $H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2$ vs $H_1:\mu_1 \ne \mu_2$?

Comment: I did the following working but its the interpretation I am having difficulty understanding??95% = 1.96
Group 1 Elevated triglyceride    
M=26.1
SD= 3.72      22.38-----29.82
n= 10
SE = SD/√n = 3.72/ 3.16 = 1.177
CI= m ± (z x SE) 
26.1 + (1.96 x 1.177) = 28.406
26.1 – (1.96 x 1.177) = 23.793
CI = 23.793 ->28.406
 
Group 2 Normal triglycerides
M=24.3
SD= 3.45      20.85----27.75
n= 15
SE= 3.45/3.873 = 0.890
CI = 24.3 ± (1.96 x 0.89)
CI=  22.556 -> 26.044

Comment: I suggest using t values, not z values.

Comment: Tip for posting comments: surround equations etc with $ (dollar signs). Anyhow, looks like you're able to get the confidence intervals just fine. (Although, you need to use t-values.) So the problem's with the second part?

Comment: It's not clear to me how to do the second part. As far as I know, non-overlapping confidence intervals don't indicate what the result of the test would be.

Comment: This is the bit I am having trouble with? ""a test of the null hypothesis of no difference against a two-sided alternative at 5% would lead to rejection or not"" I think it would lead to an acceptance of the null hypothesis but I am not sure how to say this and explain why - oh this is so frustrating!!

Comment: I think the answer that the question is looking for is that the null hypothesis would not be rejected because the confidence intervals overlap. The problem is that this reasoning is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Why do you say the reasoning is incorrect?  Sorry but I am really trying to understand what I am doing here!

Comment: The reasoning is incorrect because it is possible for the null hypothesis to be rejected even though the confidence intervals overlap.

Comment: I think my earlier comment contains a mistake - as far as I know, non-overlapping confidence intervals do imply rejection of the null hypothesis, but overlapping confidence intervals don't imply non-rejection.